# Настройка nginx + php72-fpm на macOS

Tags: nginx, macos, mac, php-fpm

Подобную настройку проводил на Ubuntu 16 и 18 без особых проблем, но с macOS на локальной машине не могу разобраться, мне кажется я не до конца понимаю основного принципа связи nginx c php-fpm. 
Я успешно настроил nginx, скачав его с менеджера пакетов brew.
Через `sudo nginx -v` я получаю

> nginx version: nginx/1.15.2

Как обычно настроил несколько сайтов через sites-available и сделать include в nginx.conf. На этом этапе все хорошо, через

```
 curl localhost, curl test.local
```

и т.д. я получаю результат.

При проверке

```
sudo php-fpm -v
```

> PHP 7.2.9 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Aug 22 2018 02:58:58)

При запуске `php7.2-fpm` на linux через `sudo service php7.2-fpm start` создается сокет в `/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`
И в файле `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/pool.d/www.conf` достаточно указать

```
Listen = /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock
Listen.owner = www-data
Listen.user = www-data
Listen.mode = 0660
```

Проделывая тоже самое на Mac, но немного в другой дирректории (структура php-fpm на Mac другая, но сути менять не должно) в `/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/php-fpm.d/www.conf`
указывая тоже самые настройки *(кроме  `Listen = /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock` я устанавливаю `Listen = /usr/localvar/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`)* при запуске `sudo php-fpm`  я получаю ошибку

> [25-Aug-2018 11:18:21] ERROR: [pool www] cannot get gid for group
>   'www-data': Undefined error: 0 (0) [25-Aug-2018 11:18:21] ERROR: FPM
>   initialization failed

Я пробовал менять настройки, указывая вместо www-data имя моего локального профиля, но это дает такую же ошибку

> [25-Aug-2018 11:18:21] ERROR: [pool www] cannot get gid for group
>   'igortulkin': Undefined error: 0 (0) [25-Aug-2018 11:18:21] ERROR: FPM
>   initialization failed

Подскажите, что я делаю не так и как правильно связать php-fpm на Mac c Nginx?

Comment: от какого пользователя на маке запускается nginx? и покажи вывод команды `id ИМЯ-ЭТОГО-ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ`

Comment: @norbornen , через sudo nginx и в мониторинге системы получаю два процесса nginx, один под root, другой под локал.уч.записью.
вот данные которые я получаю через id root
`$ id root
uid=0(root) gid=0(wheel) groups=0(wheel),1(daemon),2(kmem),3(sys),4(tty),5(operator),8(procview),9(procmod),12(everyone),20(staff),29(certusers),61(localaccounts),80(admin),701(1),33(_appstore),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)`

Comment: @norbornen а это данные которые я получаю через id igortulkin
`id igortulkin
uid=501(igortulkin) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),701(1),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh)`

Comment: Игорь, меня и интересует под какой учётной записью запущены worker-ы nginx. Тот, что в конфиге nginx-а прописан в `user`. Попробуйте прописать в конфиг пхп этого пользователя и его группу

Comment: @norbornen, я пробовал сделать именно так, прописывал и root и igortulkin(лок.учетная запись), в случае с root не работает, а с локальной учетной записью работает если указать еще и группу, т.е. так - `user igortulkin admin;`Так же прописал этого пользователя и группу в www.conf, но php-fpm при старте `sudo php-fpm`  стал выдавать
`[25-Aug-2018 21:04:13] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 6181
[25-Aug-2018 21:04:13] NOTICE: ready to handle connections` При этом сокет создается, процессы в мониторинге отображаются, но сервис как-будто стартует не верно, внутри скриптов php не отрабатывает

Comment: @norbornen права на сокет `ls -la /usr/local/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock`
насколько я понимаю установлены правильно
`srw-rw----  1 igortulkin  admin  0 25 авг 21:04 /usr/local/var/run/php7.2-fpm.sock`